# MSSQL Datetime Conversion US Format

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a problem with datetime conversions in MSSQL. We need to migrate ORACLE inserts into MSSQL acceptable inserts.

Therefore we need to change TO_DATE() calls to CONVERT(datetime..).

The date format that is given to us, is the following:

'12/31/2001 23:59:59'

We searched for the matching format on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx), but couldn't find any format matching this (as I understand) standard US format. Are we doing something wrong? Do we need to put the date and the time together in two separate converts?

An

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME , '12/31/2001 23:59:59')` should do the trick.

Comment: If the session DATEFORMAT is MDY (US English default), you don't need a function at all.  The literal '12/31/2001 23:59:59' will be inplictly converted to datetime as needed.

Comment: Thanks that should work M.Ali. Didn't think of that solution... Sometimes you're just stuck.